# SCIM service providers in WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, scim, wso2-identity-server

For which purposes wso2 identity server has **SCIM service providers** configuration page (https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS450/Registering+SCIM+Providers)?

I cant understand how to use configured service providers.

Could you explain me for which purposes there are that settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be you have mentioned about SCIM Service provider. I hope you need to know about the `Registering SCIM Providers`. Say, when you are adding a user in to the WSO2IS (using management console or API or SCIM),  you can provision that user in to some other Server that exposes SCIM end points.  SO,  you can register those servers as SCIM providers.  However with new Identity Server version, v 5.0.0, you may not found these UI.It has clearly mentioned about in-bound/out-bound provisioning capabilities. You can go through [this](http://soasecurity.org/2014/10/03/in-boundout-bound-provisioning-with-identity-server/) document and understand it well.